# Replace SECOND occurrence of word in a string with R program

Tags: r, stringr

Would like to replace first occurrence of CARS word with empty space, not replacing the middle and last occurrence

using gsub, it is replacing all the values in the column

```
CAR_ID <- c(5001,5002)
CAR_Details <- c(" CARS THIS CARS BUSINESS IS NOT JUST BUYING CARS", " CARS BUSINESS INVOLVES DEALING WITH OLD CARS AS WELL AS NEW CARS")

df1 <- data.frame(CAR_ID,CAR_Details)

df1$CAR_Details <- gsub("CARS",",df1$CAR_Details)
```

Desired output :

```
CAR_ID         CAR_Details
 5001      CARS THIS BUSINESS IS NOT JUST BUYING CARS
 5002      CARS BUSINESS INVOLVES DEALING WITH OLD AS WELL AS NEW CARS
```

Comment: Please include the exact output you expect here.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using `gsub`, just use `sub`:

```
df1$CAR_Details <- sub("CARS", " ", df1$CAR_Details)
```

By the way, the `g` in `gsub` stands for "global," meaning it will replace everywhere.  The `sub()` version will only replace the first match found, from left to right.

Comment: Sorry my bad, meant to ask - replace the second occurrence keeping the first occurrence   remain untouched.

Answer (score 0):

`stringr::str_replace` will only replace the first occurrence.

```
str_replace(df1$CAR_Details, "CARS", " ")
[1] "   THIS CARS BUSINESS IS NOT JUST BUYING CARS"                  "   BUSINESS INVOLVES DEALING WITH OLD CARS AS WELL AS NEW CARS"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two solutions:
First one is for the first question removing the first occurence of `CARS`.
Note In the first solution everything before the first space will be removed, (extra Note: in row1 we have two space therefore `trimws`)

```
df1$CAR_Details <- sub('.*? ', '', trimws(df1$CAR_Details))

  CAR_ID                                                 CAR_Details
1   5001                  THIS CARS BUSINESS IS NOT JUST BUYING CARS
2   5002 BUSINESS INVOLVES DEALING WITH OLD CARS AS WELL AS NEW CARS
```

Second solution is the updated for removing the second occurence of `CARS` (see comments in Tim Biegelsen's answer:

```
df1$CAR_Details <- sub('(CARS.*?)CARS', '\\1', trimws(df1$CAR_Details))

  CAR_ID                                                  CAR_Details
1   5001                  CARS THIS  BUSINESS IS NOT JUST BUYING CARS
2   5002 CARS BUSINESS INVOLVES DEALING WITH OLD  AS WELL AS NEW CARS
```